# Finding point on a plane closest to a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ using least squares method?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, constraints, weighted-least-squares

Suppose S is a 2d plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. it is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $ax_1+bx_2=0$ (a,b not equal to 0). Let $b=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How can I use least squares fitting to find the point in S that's closest to b? I understand it will be the projection, but how does least squares  come into play? Do I have to use formula $x_{min}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the case when it is required to find the point on the
$$\tag{1}
P:\;ax+by+cz=d
$$
closest to the origin. The coordinates of the point $Q$ on the plane described by (1) nearest to the origin are equal to the minimal norm solution of (1):
$$\tag{2}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_Q\\y_Q\\z_Q
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)^+\cdot d
$$
Now consider the case when it is required to find the point on the plane
(1)
closest to some arbitrary point $M(x_M,y_M,z_M)$. After the change of variables
$$
x'=x-x_M,\quad y'=y-y_M,\quad z'= z-z_M
$$
$M$ tranforms into the origin and (1) transforms into
$$
a(x'+x_M)+b(y'+y_M)+c(z'+z_M)=d
$$
or
$$
ax'+by'+cz'=d-ax_M-by_M-cz_M.
$$
According to (2), we obtain
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x'_Q\\y'_Q\\z'_Q
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)^+\cdot (d-ax_M-by_M-cz_M)
$$
and
$$
x_Q= x'_Q+x_M,\quad y_Q= y'_Q+y_M,\quad z_Q= z'_Q+z_M.
$$
Since $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)$ has linearly independent rows,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)^+= 
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)^T
(\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a& b &c 
\end{array}\right)^T)^{-1}
=
\frac1{a^2+b^2+c^2}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\b\\c
\end{array}\right),
$$
thus,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_Q\\y_Q\\z_Q
\end{array}\right)=
\frac{d-ax_M-by_M-cz_M}{a^2+b^2+c^2}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\b\\c
\end{array}\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_M\\y_M\\z_M
\end{array}\right).
$$